# (Angular 6) Button tag does not display

Tags: html, angular

## Hello There

I'm trying to create a login form in my web-app (Angular 6). The weird thing is that my Button tag is not showing up in the front-end. And there is no compilation error.

This is my button:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="form mt-4" (submit)="login()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input
            formControlName="password" 
            type="password" 
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Password"><br>
        <vmessage
            *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').errors?.required"
            text=" Password is required!">
        </vmessage>               
    </div>

    <button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" 
        type="submit">
        login
    </button>

</form>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
button
{
    display: initial;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Any other tag works, p tag, a tag, div tag or simply text. They all show up, but i need the button one because of the form validator. (by the way, simple button tags don't appear either)

This makes no sense for me. What am I missing here?

Comment: its present in the DOM? did you debug in chrome dev tools. Might be issue with position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO, I managed to fix this issue by putting the button tag inside a span.

If this helps someone, that's how I fixed it:

```
<span *ngIf = "loginForm.valid" >Login 
    <button type="submit">
        login
    </button>
</span>
```